# Building new release of ngx-charts

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, ngx-charts

I'm attempting to add a personally desired feature for ngx-charts. I got it to work using the standard src directory but, I wanted to build a release version potentially.

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. `npm i https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/tarball/master --save` (this grabs the entire project instead of just the release)
2. Go into your `node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-charts` folder and delete the release directory
3. Rebuild the directory by running `npm i && npm run package`
4. Notice how index.d.ts is unable to find any modules even though they're there.

I have noticed that the `/common/base-chart.component.d.ts` file is never created for some reason causing this problem. But, I cannot for the life of my figure out why. I've tried multiple webpack versions 2-4 but, every attempt results in the same thing.

I believe I am doing something wrong which is why I did not open an issue. I would appreciate any insight into this problem. Thank you for reading!

Comment: usually definition files are developed separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend cloning the repository locally rather than installing it from npm:

```
git clone git@github.com:swimlane/ngx-charts.git
```

Then install dependencies:

```
cd ngx-charts
npm install
```

After that make your changes to the src (you can run the demo app to test while developing with "npm run start")

Then to package:

```
npm run package
```

This will build the project and update the release folder